# MaxScript how to capture current rotaion

Tags: maxscript

This is my first time trying to write a script for 3ds max. I'm trying to set the selected objects pivot point rotation to (90,0,0). So far I've managed to add 90 to the the rotation everytime i run the script. I then found a solution online but I get the error: "unknown property objectoffsetrot ". Here is the script:

```
(
    fn RotatePivotOnly obj rotation = (
    local rotValInv=inverse (rotation as quat)
    animate off in coordsys local obj.rotation = RotValInv
    obj.objectoffsetrot *=RotValInv
    obj.objectoffsetpos *= RotValInv
)

fn RotatePivotAbsolute obj rotation =
(
        currentRot=obj.objectoffsetrot as quat
        wantRot = rotation 
        needRot =(currentRot as quat - wantRot as quat) as eulerangles
        RotatePivotOnly obj needRot
)

if (b = selection as array)[1] == undefined then
b = box()

b.pivot=[0,0,0] 
RotatePivotAbsolute b (EulerAngles 90 0 0) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this two step method. Transform obj and then rotate it back:

```
if (b = selection as array)[1] == undefined then
(
b = box()
b.pivot=[0,0,0] 

absrot = eulerAngles 90 0 0
absrotmat = (absrot as quat) as matrix3
b.transform = absrotmat 
b.objectOffsetRot = inverse absrotmat.rotationPart
)
```